# How do I access iPhone's ringtones for my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to make an alarm clock app for iPhone (using Swift). I want to sound option to have the default ringtones in iPhone (just like the built-in alarm clock app in iPhone). What is the path directory for it? How do I access it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ringtones in Clock App are not accessible for other apps.
You can download these ringtones and include in your Bundle App.